# Is it possible to determine if a message has been signed by a certificate in the same chain?

Tags: certificate, keychain, sign

I have a certificate chain that looks like this

```
Root cert -> Intermediate (sub-root) cert -> leaf cert
```

If I sign a message/token using the leaf cert and send it to the destination.

Now, at the destination I have only the Intermediate cert. Is it possible to check if the message has been signed by the leaf (or a certificate that belongs to the same chain as Intermediate cert)?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates have an **Issuer** - the one who signed it. Talking about your scenario it is the **Intermediate**. So when looking at the leaf certificate you will see the `IssuerName`, which is the subject name of the certificate that was used to sign. Additionally you may find an `Authority Key Iddentifier` (AKI) which is an extension but cryptographic evidence instead of just a string (what the issuer name is). These values are the **same** on every issued certificate by a certain CA.

[image]

Th first issued certificate:

[image]

[image]

And now another certificate issued by **R3**:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you sign a message/token with a leaf certificate and send it to a destination WITHOUT sending the leaf certificate that you used (so you only send the signature itself) and WITHOUT the recipient knowing that certificate beforehand.

In this case, it's not possible to check that the signature was performed with a certificate that is itself signed with the intermediate certificate. In fact, it's impossible to even check that the signature is correct because you are lacking the public key that is stored in the certificate (and not in the signature).

Any time you send a signature you have to either ensure that the recipient already has the leaf certificate used to sign it, or you can send the certificate along with the signature. The recipient will then check that the signature is correctly signed by the certificate you are sending and will check that the certificate has been signed by an intermediate certificate the recipient already knows (just as @Daniel indicates in his answer).

Comment: I assumed a PKCS#7 signature which usually includes the certificate, but must not include it, and can even include the complete chain. Without the certificate - or better said its public key - it is not possible to validate the signature...